# delete a combination of string with sed

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I delete some strings in the lines of a text with sed command:

```
sed 's:\(pattern\.\)::g' file
```

But certain patterns have letters and numbers:

```
sed 's:\(pattern\.\|pattern1\.\|pattern2\.\|pattern23\.\|patternx\.\|patternYx\.\)::g' file
```

a long etc...

How to delete pattern (always is the same) + numbers (any combination 0-9) and letters (A-Z, a-z) in one single line, to avoid repeat "pattern+something"

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove `pattern` followed by zero or more numbers or letters followed by `.`, use:

```
sed 's:pattern[[:alnum:]]*\.::g'
```

Notes:

1. The regex doesn't use the parens grouping, `\(...\)`, so I removed it.
2. `[[:alnum:]]` matches any letter or number.
3. `[[:alnum:]]*` matches zero or more of any letter or number.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to delete lines containing a pattern, then use `sed`'s delete command `d`.

Try this:

```
$ sed '/pattern.*/d' file
```

Comment: Please, read the question again and explain what makes you think that OP wants to delete whole lines.